# Any way to copy data into a component in another thread?

Tags: unity, multithreading

Pretty sure the answer to this is a resounding no but just in case...

Running an expensive algorithm in a separate thread. However, it returns data that must be copied into the arrays of a Shapes.Polyline (plugin takes an array of custom point objects), and into the Vector2 array of an edge collider.

Still a noticeable dip in framerate as it copies the data into those collections (it's a lot of vectors).

Is there any way at all to do those last steps in a separate thread?

Or will I have to use a coroutine to spread it over several frames?

Comment: DMGregory was right as usual. The vast majority of the time was spent both updating the new EdgeCollider and in fact deleting the old one. Staggering both the creation and destruction of the colliders over several frames with shorter chunks allows it to generate a new section without dropping a single frame. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not the copying that's taking the time, but the updating of the rendered polygons and collision detection acceleration structures in response to the newly-copied data.

Since those operations are changing the state of data that's in use every frame to step the simulation and render the result, it can't be done in parallel with those activities. You need to do it on the main thread in between simulation steps / renders.

You can probably reduce or eliminate the noticeable hitch by splitting the work into smaller parts - say making n polylines that join end-to-end to create the same look as one continuous polyline. Then you can update one of those n segments in a frame, and update the next segment next frame, so no single frame has to bear the burden of recalculating all of the rendered and collision geometry.

Comment: That makes sense.
Given that the area being generated is off screen at the time, is there any way to calculate those collision structures in a disabled state so they are not required by the simulation until calculated?

Comment: You could test whether the cost is lower when disabling the collider before performing the copy, but you'd likely still incur the hitch when you re-enable it and all that same work needs to be done all at once.